# Dynamic sized int list

Tags: c++

I would like to create a int list in C++, but it just doesn't make sense at all.

Also I don't want it to have static size.

I tried this, but "array size must be specified in new expressions without an initializer", what should I do?

```
int* list = {};
int* list = new int[];
int list[];
```

Full code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* list = new int[];

int main() {
    int num;
    cout << "Select number > ";
    cin >> num;

    rozloz(num, list);

    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]); j++) {
        cout << list[j] << endl;
    }
}

int avaible[] = { 5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1 };

void rozloz(int num, int* list) {
    int i = 0;
    int i2 = 0;

    while (num > 0) {
        int current = avaible[i];

        if (current > num) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        list[i2] = current;
        num -= current;
        i2++;
    };
}
```

Comment: You need to use `std::vector<int>`. The language does not support lists, the only underlying container available are arrays and they are not resizable. You need to use the standard library features which provides higher level functionalities.

Comment: You can also use some stack based allocator i.e. `alloca` to get dynamic memory on the stack, but unless you understand what the pros and cons are and what to watch out for you should stick with the `std::vector` answer

Comment: Don't do `using namespace std;` because there is already a `std::list` which will confuse your compiler.

Comment: Oh, I see.. Thanks!

Comment: Arrays must have a fixed capacity when they are created.  If you need to change the capacity, allocate a **new** array, copy old elements to new array, then **delete** the old array.  Or use `std::vector` which does all this for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "array size must be specified in new expressions without an initializer", what should I do?

As per the error message, you should specify a size when you create an array. That size determines how many elements the array has. That said, you normally shouldn't use allocating `new` expressions at all. See end of the answer for a recommendable solution.

> ```
> sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0])
> ```

This is wrong. This works only with arrays. I recommend using `std::size` with arrays, so that you won't encounter this problem because the program would safely fail to compile instead of give you the wrong size.

The type of `list` is not an array type. Its type is "pointer to `int`". It points to first element of a dynamic array.

The most convenient way to create a dynamic array is to use `std::vector` from the standard library. Example:

```
std::vector<int> rozloz(int num) {
    std::vector<int> list;
    //...
    list.push_back(current); // add elements like this
    //...
    return list;
}
```